# Intersection of Open Connected Sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the intersection of two open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the usual topology) also a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Hint: Not all open sets are convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the intersection of a fat circle with a fat line? Is it connected in general?